# AdonisJS migration Error on PostgreSQL : withSchema is not a function

Tags: knex.js, adonis.js

I want to create a DB under non-public Schema in PostgreSQL.
In knexjs document :

```
knex.schema.withSchema('public').createTable('users', function (table){
  table.increments();
})
```

My migration code is:

```
this.withSchema('myschema').create('users', table => {
  table.increments()
})
```

But migration:run returns this error:

```
TypeError: this.withSchema is not a function
```

How can I create DB under custom schema?

Comment: paste you full code here.

Comment: @FazalRasel : My code is very simple , only add a table with id under myschema , schema . Also I created schema before running migration.

Comment: and your simple code is not working. To identify actual problem, full file code is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Example from knex docs actually does work:

https://runkit.com/embed/zbhlv44ry8xf

Seems like `this` in your migration code is not `knex` instance.

Comment: Provide enough context of your code so that one can figure out why your `this` is not the knex instance that you seem to think it is. Maybe you are trying to do subquery and using arrow function as callback, which does not bind `this` correctly.